# What's a formal term for the informal verb "floated"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Sample sentence:

> In a meeting with the mechanic, I **floated** that I might be interested in buying the vehicle.

What respectful — non-slang — words or phrase could I use here instead of "floated"?

In Hungarian, the formal variant is a phrase: 'kilátásba helyez'

What I have tried:

- I probed my memory for two days: somehow it feels like it's on the tip of my tongue, but I couldn't catch it.
- put the Hungarian term into the biggest Hungarian-operated dictionary (no luck)
- put the Hungarian term into Google Translate (no-no)
- put the Hungarian term into Bing Translate (yay: maybe it has to do with **prospect**?)
- thesaurus.com (only pieces of wood floating there)

Comment: *Suggested* works here, or heck, you could just use *said*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex cool indeed! But: "you could just use _said_" then I would not learn anything! Also: now I have to _sratch this itch!_ Also: my writing style is admittedly a bit embellished otherwise: "said" in its short simplicity would stand out.

Comment: The idiom is: **to float an idea**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "raised the idea" or "raised the prospect." But "floated the idea" is not slang, nor would I classify it as very informal.

Comment: What if I "floated the prospect"? Would that ruin it? Would that risk of taking away from its non-slang-ness?

Comment: I have done a web search, and I had found a lot of results like this: "In reaction to the dam idea, the Indian government has **floated the prospect** of building another dam [...]", so, let's just say I'm very happy. Thank you.

Comment: On further searches I found that "raised the prospect" is somehow different, but I have hard time to put my finger on how, right now. "**Floating the prospect**" however, had serially shown up as consistent with my scenario, and with formal settings. So if you added this variant in the answer, (while, optionally, explained the slight difference involving "**raising the prospect**") I could accept this.

Comment: Further results: "The governor of the Bank of England has **raised the prospect** that, after Brexit [...]" (From a British publication); "Texas Democrats **raised the prospect** Wednesday that a change in the way Texas reports election results [...]" from a Texan press channell. I conclude, your answer is already acceptable. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [definition of "floated"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/floated) that applies is *To offer for consideration; suggest: floated my idea to the committee.* I don't know the exact nuance of the Hungarian, but I assume you want to express that you made a proposal to see how someone might react to it instead of making a firm proposal to ask someone to decide yes or no.

You could use "[hinted](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hinted)", or *To express or state indirectly*:

> In a meeting with the mechanic, I **hinted** that I might be interested in buying the vehicle.

"[Suggested](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/suggested)", or *To express or say indirectly: The police officer seemed to be suggesting that the death was not an accident.*, might also work.

> In a meeting with the mechanic, I **suggested** that I might be interested in buying the vehicle.

"Hinted" is a little more indirect in my opinion than "suggested".

Comment: I will remember these when the nuance in context will benefit these! Thank you.